# Using :contains() Selector on a label to affect an input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Just discovered the jQuery `:contains()` selector and would like to use it however the text to find is on a label attribute and I want the following code to effect the corresponding input.

```
<input type="radio" name="Opt2031" id="OptID20312026" value="1" /><label style="cursor:pointer" for="OptID20312026">Equipment Hire</label>
```

So what I want to do is get labels that contain equipment hire `$("label:contains('Equipment Hire')");` and then if the do change the value of the associating input `$('#OptID20312026').val('14')`

Comment: The corresponding input is already there; you don't need to effect it. Or maybe you meant "affect"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var labelFor = $("label:contains('Equipment Hire')").attr("for");
$("#" + labelFor).val('14');
```